# dynamically update URL when editing inline SLUG in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have a page with URL http://example.com/blogs/lorem-ipsum

If user is signed in and owner of the post, they have the inline option to edit SLUG(or name which is generating the slug).

Question is, if they do edit the SLUG, how can I dynamically update the `lorem-ipsum` in the URL?

Below is the Route code, I am using UI Router

```
app.config([
  "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider.state("root", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "root.html"
    }).state("root.blogs", {
      url: "^/blogs",
      views: {
        'content@root': {
          templateUrl: "blogs/index.html",
          controller: "BlogsController"
        }
      }
    }).state("root.blogs.show", {
      url: "^/blogs/:slug",
      views: {
        'content@root': {
          templateUrl: "blogs/show.html",
          controller: "BlogsController"
        }
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: where's your routing code ?

Comment: hmm, still no answer, too bad, i am also looking for an answer. Will be back when I found one